# How do I properly use multimarker in an xml file?

Tags: ros, xml, marker, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to detect three AR trackers with the ar_track_alvar package [link ar_track_alvar package](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar). The three trackers should be detected as a bundle.
My xml file which describes the markers looks as follows:

```
<marker index="0" status="1">
  <corner x="-3.45" y="-3.45" z="0" />
  <corner x="3.45" y="-3.45" z="0" />
  <corner x="3.45" y="3.45" z="0" />
  <corner x="-3.45" y="3.45" z="0" />
</marker>

<marker index="1" status="1">
  <corner x="-3.45" y="-16.85" z="0" />
  <corner x="3.45" y="-16.85" z="0" />
  <corner x="3.45" y="-9.95" z="0" />
  <corner x="-3.45" y="-9.95" z="0" />
</marker>

<marker index="2" status="1">
  <corner x="21.15" y="-16.85" z="0" />
  <corner x="28.05" y="-16.85" z="0" />
  <corner x="28.05" y="-9.95" z="0" />
  <corner x="21.15" y="-9.95" z="0" />
</marker>
```

- As far as I understood the first marker has to have index 0. For the other markers the index does not matter, right?
- What does the **status** mean? What arguments are valid?
- Sometimes I get the following error: *ERROR InferCorners: "ar_marker_0" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.* Sometimes it is also another marker number. How can I avoid this error or what is the reason for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271353/how-do-i-properly-use-multimarker-in-an-xml-file?/) by [phi_abs](https://answers.ros.org/users/31990/phi_abs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an old one, but I've just been working out the answers to a few of these questions myself so I thought I'd add them here. I'll answer your three questions separately.

1. The first marker index in the bundle
   XML file can be any marker on you
   object, it can but doesn't have to
   be marker zero. The other marker
   indices must correspond their the
   appropriate marker number used.
2. Status was a bit of mystery until I
   dug into the source code, it seems
   there is some support for extra
   corner features on the objects as
   well the marker tags but I haven't
   attempted to get this working yet.
   From experimentation we've had it
   working fine with a status of 1 or 2.
3. I can't help you with this one I'm afraid, we've not experienced
   this error on our setup.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0